# how to determine if a user has confirmed or canceled signin via facebook javascript sdk

Tags: facebook, web, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am logging users into a web site via facebook's Javascript SDK.  After the user clicks the "log in through fb" button, I would like to generate different responses depending on whether the user click "ok" or "cancel" in facebook's confirmation.  Here is the code I use when they click the fb button.

```
$("#fb").click(function() {
    FB.login(function(response){
        FB.api('/me',function(response){

            // I believe the test to see if they are logged in or not should go here

        });//FB.api
    },{scope:'publish_actions, email, user_likes, user_location'});
});
```

Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to facebook's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    alert('a');
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
    alert('b');
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
    alert('c');
  }
 });
```

It worked for me.  Hope it helps someone else.